# When does the closure capture the variable value (defined in an outer function) in javascript: when nested function is defined or executed?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures

I understand that scope is created when a function is defined. But I am not sure if I comprehend correctly if the variable value (defined in a function & referenced in inner function, aka closure) is captured also when the nested function is defined , Or, when it is executed.

In the well known closure in loop Scenario, the closure seems to capture the "i" value when the loop finishes. Assuming loop through 5 times, then "i" would be 4. Hence "i" would be captured as 4. Therefore it looks like "i" is only captured when nested function is executed?

It would be appreciated if someone can point out where the capture is happening.

**Scenario 1**

```
var fnName = function(x){           
    return function(){ return ++x; };   // (is x value captured here?)
};
var fnName1 = fnName(0);    
fnName1();              // x=1 (is x value captured here?)
fnName1();              // x=2
```

**Scenario 2**

```
var fnName = function(){    
var x = 0;  
    return function(){ return ++x; };   // (is x value captured here?)
};
var fnName1 = fnName(); 
fnName1();              // x=1 (is x value captured here?)
fnName1();              // x=2
```

**Scenario 3**

```
var fnName = function(){            
    var x = 0;              
    function runFn(){ return x++; };    // (is x value captured here?)
    runFn();            
};
fnName();               // x=0
fnName();               // x=0
```

Comment: The key thing to understand is that closures don't close over the *value* of a variable, they close over *the variable*. They have an enduring reference to the actual variable, not its value at a specific point in time.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. This clarifies a few different concepts for me.

Comment: @ Charles: Happy to help. You may find my blog post on this useful: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Strangely the article did not come up in google search when I used to search for closure or scope. but it is the exact article I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *variable* is captured when it is declared. The value **isn't** captured (which is why it can change).

```
var fnName = function(x){ // Here
    return function(){ return ++x; };
};


var fnName = function(){    
var x = 0;  // Here (but remember that hoisting exists)
    return function(){ return ++x; };
};
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems I misused the "capture" terminology. In this case, is it correct to say variable hoisting & initialization happen when nested function is called?

Comment: @Charles: The code `var x = 0` actually contains two completely separate things that happen at completely separate times: It's a variable declaration (`var x`), and it's an assignment operation (`x = 0`). All variable declarations within a function are processed when the function is called, *before* any step-by-step code is processed. So even if the `var x` is 10 lines down, it is handled before those lines are run. That's why people say those declarations are "hoisted" to the top. The *assignment*, though, stays where it is.

Comment: @Charles: In the second example above, the `x` within `fnName` is created and assigned when `fnName` is run, not when the function it returns is run. E.g., `f = fnName();` creates the `x` variable that `f` closes over. Calling `f()` *uses* that variable.

Comment: Hoisting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: This answer is confusing. What is the difference between a variable being captured and a value being captured? Are we talking about the value of the same variable? And, also, I know that variables are captured when the closure is declared, not when it's called. A closure is created at declaration time. Primitives, including strings that are "closed" upon, get copied at closure declaration time, object references get copied as well, but point to the same object, not the same variable, of course. Correct me if I'm wrong.